# Error when i try launching my android aplication (A viewFlipper)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, compiler-errors

I have made an app which takes the photos from the SDcard and puts them on a `ViewFlipper`, but when i launch it, it suddenly stops.

I have no errors in eclipse(ițs an android app).

Here is the java code:

```
public class Images extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
    static Button btnNext;
    static Button btnBack;
    static ViewFlipper Flipper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.images);
    final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/images");
    btnNext= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    btnBack= (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_minus);
    Flipper=(ViewFlipper) findViewById (R.id.flipper);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    final int imageCount = f.listFiles().length;
      for (int count = 0; count < imageCount - 1; count++) {
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.listFiles()[count].getAbsolutePath());
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
      Flipper.addView(imageView);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()){

        case(R.id.btn_minus):
         Flipper.showPrevious();
        break;

        case(R.id.btn_plus):
         Flipper.showNext();    
        break;  
        }
    }
}
```

here is the logcat:

```
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tendarius.voicebrowser/com.tendarius.voicebrowser.Images}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.tendarius.voicebrowser.Images.onCreate(Images.java:36)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: make sure you have added SD-CARD permissions in AndroidManifest ?

Comment: do you really need the imports and empty lines in the question ?

Comment: 1.  No errors in Eclipse is meaningless, since you cannot run your app if you have any and, you cannot get runtime errors until you fix compile time errors. 2. Please always post the logcat stack trace when asking about exceptions.  3. You should learn how to read logcat and how to use the debugger then this problem would be very easy for you to find.

Comment: Posting stacktrace will certainly help.. here is [a link](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/) to help you understand the same...

Comment: I've added the logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 08:22:29.418: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.tendarius.voicebrowser.Images.onCreate(Images.java:36)
```

Looks like your problem is on line36. Make sure that you're referring to an object that is not null. For example,

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
-> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() must not be null

imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
-> imageView must not be null

set a breakpoint on line 36 and see if there is an object that is null then find out the reason it becomes null - perhaps it might be due to a resource that is not available to your application